# Why is null in JavaScript bigger than -1, less than 1, but not equal (==) to 0? What is it exactly then?

Tags: javascript

From the Google Chrome console:

```
var x = null;
undefined
x > 0
false
x < 0
false
x > -1
true
x < 1
true
x == 1
false
x === 1
false
```

Comment: Not a number, so the assessment is inherently false?

Comment: Note `null >= 0`, etc. is true

Comment: Even more strangely, `null <= 0` is true, but both `null < 0` and `null == 0` are false

Answer (score 101, accepted):

When you compare null for equality to 0, the result is false. If you force `null` to be interpreted in a numeric context then it is treated like 0 and the result becomes true.

You can force it to be numeric by putting `+` in front, or by using numeric operators like `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. Notice how `null >= 0` and `null <= 0` are both true.

```
> null == 0
false
> +null == 0
true
> null >= 0
true
> null <= 0
true
```

---

The [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) defines when a so-called "ToNumber" conversion is performed. When it is, null and false are both converted to 0.

> #### [§9.1 Type Conversion and Testing](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-9.html#a-9.3):
>
> Table 14 — To Number Conversions
>
> ```
> Argument Type     Result
> -------------     ------
> Undefined         Return NaN
> Null              Return +0
> Boolean           Return 1 if argument is true. Return +0 if argument is false.
> Number            Return argument (no conversion).
> String            See grammar and note below.
> ```

Knowing when the ToNumber conversion is applied depends on the operator in question. For the relational operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` see:

> #### [§11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-11.html#a-11.8.5):
>
> The comparison `x < y`, where x and y are values, produces **true**, **false**,
>   or **undefined** (which indicates that at least one operand is **NaN**). Such
>   a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. Call ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
> 2. Call ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).
> 3. If Type(Result(1)) is String and Type(Result(2)) is String, go to step 16. (Note that this step differs from step 7 in the algorithm for
>      the addition operator + in using and instead of or.)
> 4. Call ToNumber(Result(1)).
> 5. Call ToNumber(Result(2)).

The `==` operator is different. Its type conversions are described below. Notice how null and false follow different rules.

> #### [§11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-11.html#a-11.9.3)
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces **true** or
>   **false**. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), go to step 14.
>
> ...
>
> 14. If x is **null** and y is **undefined**, return **true**.
>
> 15. If x is **undefined** and y is **null**, return **true**.
>
> 16. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
>
> 17. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> 18. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
>
> 19. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
>
> 20. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
>
> 21. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
>
> 22. Return **false**.

If you read carefully you can see why `false == 0` is true but `null == 0` is false.

- For `false == 0`, Type(x) is Boolean. This means Step 18's type conversion is applied, and false is converted to a number. ToNumber(false) is 0, and `0 == 0` is true, so the comparison succeeds.
- For `null == 0`, Type(x) is Null. None of the type checks match so the comparison falls through to Step 22, which returns false. The comparison fails.

Comment: If someone does not know `null >=0`; that could lead to some very troubling bugs. Suppose one allowing a user to do something when their balance is greater than zero; but got null for some reason from API; & they did not check for null (` x != null`)

Answer (score 13):

null casts to 0 as a number: `(+null)` is 0. > and < cast null to this value, so when compared to numbers it acts as zero. `==` doesn't cast null to a number, so `null == 0` is false.

Comment: Yes - + can be used to quickly cast things to numbers: `(+new Date())` is a common trick to get millisecond time. For instance, `4 + '4' = 44`, while `4 + (+'4') = 8`