# Compare String to null value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am comparing the value `null` to a string. However the result of the comparison is always `false`.

```
null > "a" // false

null < "a" // false

"a" > null // false

"a" > null // false
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I did find a section (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) within the ECMAScript standard that seems to explain what is going on, but I do not really understand what the standard says.

Comment: Where's that question on SO with 1000 upvotes that talked about string comparison in javascript? Anybody?

Comment: I think this post answers your question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407544/why-null-in-javascript-is-bigger-than-1-less-than-1-but-not-equal-to-0

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: @DeanMeehan It does. And before I asked the question I also searched SO for an answer. But the question that was linked above, was talking about numbers copared to null and not strings. That is  why I could not find it even though the answer to both questions is similar.

Comment: And this matters because...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11.8.5 is the abstract relational expression, the [*production* relational expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1) is what you need to look at, which includes the abstract one.

```
11.8.1 The Less-than Operator ( < ) // pretty much the same as >

The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression < ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:

    1) Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
    2) Let lval be GetValue(lref).
    3) Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
    4) Let rval be GetValue(rref).
--> 5) Let r be the result of performing abstract relational comparison 
       lval < rval. (see 11.8.5)
--> 6) If r is undefined, return false. Otherwise, return r.
```

When you look at the abstract relation comparison, the result will be **undefined** because `Number('a')` => `NaN` (Rule 3) which will set off these rules: *If nx is NaN, return undefined* or *If ny is NaN, return undefined*.

So 6) *Let r be the result of performing abstract relational comparison*, in your cases `r` is then undefined.  The last step says *if `r` is undefined then return `false`*, hence your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both section 3 and 4 of the reference say "return false" if nothing else is true.

There simply aren't any other options given the spec you've quoted.

Not that having it be either greater or less than would make any sense anyway.