# JavaScript, Automatic Type Conversion with "null"

Tags: javascript

Why is it that with ***null***, the automatic type conversion is different with different binary operators?

```
console.log(null * 8) // => 0 * 8 => 0
console.log(null == 0) // => false
```

Therefore with the second statement, ***null*** doesn't get type coerced to a 0.

Comment: The language is defined that way. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Not a specific problem I'm trying to solve, simply curious as to why the language works this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407544/why-null-in-javascript-is-bigger-than-1-less-than-1-but-not-equal-to-0

Comment: `typeof null === 'object'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, when you want to [multiply](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), both operands must be numbers. Therefore, JS uses the [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-tonumber) abstract operation, and ToNumber(null) is 0.

When you [compare](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), the values don't need to be numbers. It makes sense to compare non-numerical values. So null is not coerced to a number.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is coerced to `+0` for numeric operations. However, `==` is not a numeric operator and no type coercion is done thus giving `null == 0` as `false`.