# Javascript: null==0 returns false, but null<1 returns true. Please explain

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

very weird behaviour indeed.

Please explain the implicit conversions that happen in each case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407544/why-is-null-in-javascript-bigger-than-1-less-than-1-but-not-equal-to-0

Comment: `null` is not *equal* to 0 so `null == 0` correctly yields false. Only if you use an explicit type conversion `+null == 0` it will return true. In the case of `null < 1` null will automatically be converted to a number (0) therefore `0 < 1` yields true.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness  *"Traditionally, and according to ECMAScript, all objects are loosely unequal to undefined and null. But most browsers permit a very narrow class of objects (specifically, the document.all object for any page), in some contexts, to act as if they emulate the value undefined. Loose equality is one such context: null == A and undefined == A evaluate to true if, and only if, A is an object that emulates undefined. In all other cases an object is never loosely equal to undefined or null."*

Answer (score 0):

`null` will be converted to the number `0` (because `<` works with numbers), and `0` is less than `1`.

Comment: that doesn't explain the equality case though

Comment: And it also does not explain why `null` suddenly is a number in the `null < 1`-case

Comment: @KooiInc The answer clearly states that `null` gets converted to a number because of the use of `<`.