# Node.js- null is not equal to 0 or greater than 0 but it is greater than or equal to 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, null

Today I noticed that this node.js code:

```js
console.log(null==0);
console.log(null>0);
console.log(null>=0);
```

Gives the output

```
False
False
True
```

This is very weird; if something is not equal to 0 or greater than 0, then why is it greater than or equal to 0? What is happening?

Comment: Because Javascript is weird

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407585/10839188

Answer (score 0):

Because the Greater-than-or-equal operator works differently than the Equals Operator. The Greater-than-or-equal Operator converts null into 0, while the Equals Operator does not convert null to a number.

Further Explanation: https://blog.campvanilla.com/javascript-the-curious-case-of-null-0-7b131644e274